# App crashes during PDF comparison using PDFKIT in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, pdfkit, ios-pdfkit

I've developed a **NativeModule** for my app, which, compare two PDFs and summarize the changing result, and send it back to the React Native Bridge. Here are the codes I am using, and these codes work if the PDF contains less than 100 pages, however, when the pages increases the App crashes due to the **Memory issue**.

Native Module (PDF Manager):

```
import Foundation
import PDFKit
import SwiftDiff

@objc(PDFManager)
class PDFManager: NSObject {
  
  private var currentPageIndex: Int = 0
  private var lastProcessedIndex: Int = 0
  
  @objc
  func compareAndMerge(_ pdfPath1: String, pdfPath2: String, documentName: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    do {
      guard let firstPdfURL = URL(string: pdfPath1),
            let secondPdfURL = URL(string: pdfPath2) else {
        reject("pdfInvalidPath", "Invalid PDF path", nil)
        return
      }
      
      guard let pdf1 = PDFDocument(url: firstPdfURL),
            let pdf2 = PDFDocument(url: secondPdfURL) else {
        reject("PDFLoadError", "Failed to load PDFs", nil)
        return
      }
      
      let summary = try compareAndSummarize(doc1: pdf1, doc2: pdf2)
      let json = summarizeToJSON(summary: summary)
      resolve(json)
    } catch {
      print("Error merging PDFs:", error)
      reject("pdfMergeError", "Error merging PDFs", nil)
    }
  }
  
  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
  private func compareAndSummarize(doc1: PDFDocument, doc2: PDFDocument) throws -> (String, Int) {
    var changesSummary = ""
    var pagesChanged = 0
    // Iterate over pages of doc1 and doc2 simultaneously
    let pageCount = min(doc1.pageCount, doc2.pageCount)
    for pageIndex in 0..<pageCount {
      autoreleasepool {
        guard let page1 = doc1.page(at: pageIndex),
              let page2 = doc2.page(at: pageIndex) else { return }
        let page1Text = page1.string ?? ""
        let page2Text = page2.string ?? ""
        changesSummary += "Page \(pageIndex + 1):\n"
        
        // Calculate differences between the text of the two pages
        let diff = diff(text1: page1Text, text2: page2Text)
        var pageChanged = false
        // Process each change in the differences
        for change in diff {
          switch change {
          case .delete(let value):
            pageChanged = true
            changesSummary += "- Deleted: \(value)\n"
          case .insert(let value):
            pageChanged = true
            changesSummary += "+ Inserted: \(value)\n"
          case .equal( _):
            break
          }
        }
        if pageChanged {
          pagesChanged += 1
        }
      }
    }
    return (changesSummary, pagesChanged)
  }

  func summarizeToJSON(summary: (String, Int)) -> String {
    let dictionary: [String: Any] = ["changes": summary.0, "pagesChanged": summary.0]
    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [.prettyPrinted])
    return String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
  }

}
```

React Native Codes:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, NativeModules, View, useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native';
import Text from '../../Components/Text';
import s from '../../assets/styles';
import {Button} from '../../Components/Buttons';
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';
import {useSafeAreaInsets} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

function HomeScreen() {
  const [pdf1, setPDF1] = useState(null);
  const [pdf2, setPDF2] = useState(null);
  const [merging, setMerging] = useState(false);
  const {PDFManager} = NativeModules;
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const {width} = useWindowDimensions();
  const buttonWidth = width / 2 - 25;

  const selectFirstPDF = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
        type: DocumentPicker.types.pdf,
        copyTo: 'cachesDirectory',
      });
      if (!result?.fileCopyUri) {
        return;
      }
      setPDF1(result);
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  const selectSecondPDF = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
        type: DocumentPicker.types.pdf,
        copyTo: 'cachesDirectory',
      });
      if (!result?.fileCopyUri) {
        return;
      }
      setPDF2(result);
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  const updateManuals = async () => {
    setMerging(true);
    try {
      const result = await PDFManager.compareAndMerge(
        pdf1?.fileCopyUri,
        pdf2?.fileCopyUri,
        `${pdf2?.name}_PDFCompared.pdf`,
      );
      setMerging(false);
      if (result) {
        const json = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log('json -> ', json);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error -> ', error);
    } finally {
      setMerging(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={[s.flex1, {paddingTop: insets.top}, s.jcac]}>
      <View style={[s.mHor10]}>
        <Text style={[s.f30, s.ls2, s.fontBlack, s.textCenter, s.as]}>
          Keep Highlights
        </Text>
        <Text style={[s.fontSemiBold, s.mVer10]}>
          Effortlessly compare your PDF manuals and keep your highlights
          updated. Files are compared locally and your data always remain
          confidential.
        </Text>
        <View style={[s.flexRow, s.aic, s.jsb, s.mVer10]}>
          <Button
            title={pdf1?.name ? pdf1?.name : 'Highlighted PDF'}
            style={[s.bgPurple, s.br30, {width: buttonWidth}, s.me10]}
            textStyle={[s.fontMedium, s.f14, s.textWhite]}
            onPress={selectFirstPDF}
          />
          <Button
            title={pdf2?.name ? pdf2?.name : 'Updated manual'}
            onPress={selectSecondPDF}
            textStyle={[s.fontMedium, s.f14, s.textWhite]}
            style={[s.br30, {width: buttonWidth}]}
          />
        </View>
        <Button
          title={'Get updated manual'}
          isDisabled={!pdf1?.fileCopyUri || !pdf2?.fileCopyUri}
          onPress={updateManuals}
        />
        {merging && <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} color={'white'}/>}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

I tried different tips and methods like: **autorelease**.

Comment: You haven't included all code but it seems to be some serious flaws in your logic that could make the memory footprint grow. Say you have a document with X pages  and then insert a new page at the start then you will add all the pages of the old document to changesSummary even though only one page has been inserted (unless you want to include the page number as a change). It also looks to me like pages added to the end will be ignored from the final result. And if some text has been added to a page which leads to some old text being pushed to the next page then is that 1 or 2 changed pages?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks alot sir for your help pointing me out the issue. I got you a little bit, however, I am still unable to get the part that why the app crashes, and how can I avoid it from crashing. And regarding your question about text being pushed to the next page, than yes, it is considered to be 2 changed pages. Also sharing some codes may be appreciated. Thanks in advance.